# Mockgen/Go Mock on Sqlx db

Tags: go, gomock

**Structure:**

```
.
├── config
│   └── config.go
├── internal
│   ├── api
│   │   └── app.go
│   ├── handler
│   │   ├── common.go
│   │   └── users.go
│   ├── model
│   │   └── model.go
│   └── queries
│       └── queries.go
└── main.go
```

**main.go:**

```
package main

import (
    "GO_APP/internal/api"
    "GO_APP/config"
)

func main() {
    config := config.GetConfig()

    app := &api.App{}
    app.Initialize(config)
    app.Run(":8004")
}
```

**app.go:**

```
package api

import (
    "GO_APP/internal/handler"
    "GO_APP/internal/model"
    "GO_APP/config"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "github.com/jmoiron/sqlx"
    "github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter"
)

// App has router and db instances
type App struct {
    Router *httprouter.Router//mux.Router
    DB     *sqlx.DB
}

// App initialize with predefined configuration
func (a *App) Initialize(config *config.Config) {
    dbURI := fmt.Sprintf("host=%s port=%d user=%s password=%s dbname=%s sslmode=disable",
        config.DB.Host,
        config.DB.Port,
        config.DB.User,
        config.DB.Password,
        config.DB.DBname,
    )

    db, err := sqlx.Connect(config.DB.Dialect, dbURI)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Could not connect database")
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("Connected to database\n")
    }

    a.DB = model.DBMigrate(db)
    a.Router = httprouter.New()
    a.setRouters()
}

// https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin/issues/1681
// Set all required routers
func (a *App) setRouters() {
    router := a.Router
    // Routing for handling the projects
    router.GET("/users", a.GetAllUser)
    router.GET("/users/:id", a.GetUser)
    router.GET("/users/:id/address", a.GetUserAddress)
    router.POST("/users", a.CreateUser)
    router.POST("/users/:id/add_address", a.CreateUserAddress)
    router.PUT("/users/:id/update_user", a.UpdateUser)
    router.PUT("/users/:id/update_address/:addr_id", a.UpdateUserAddress)
    router.PUT("/users/:id/disable", a.DisableUser)
    router.PUT("/users/:id/enable", a.EnableUser)
    router.DELETE("/users/:id", a.DeleteUser)
    router.DELETE("/users/:id/del/:addr_id", a.DeleteUserAddress)
}

func (a *App) CreateUser(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, ps httprouter.Params) {
    handler.CreateUser(a.DB, w, r)
}

// Handlers to manage User Data
func (a *App) GetUser(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, ps httprouter.Params) {
    handler.GetUser(a.DB, w, r, ps)
}

func (a *App) GetAllUser(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, ps httprouter.Params) {
    handler.GetAllUser(a.DB, w, r)
}

func (a *App) GetUserAddress(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, ps httprouter.Params) {
    handler.GetUserAddress(a.DB, w, r, ps)
}

func (a *App) CreateUserAddress(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, ps httprouter.Params) {
    handler.CreateUserAddress(a.DB, w, r, ps)
}

func (a *App) UpdateUser(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, ps httprouter.Params) {
    handler.UpdateUser(a.DB, w, r, ps)
}

func (a *App) UpdateUserAddress(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, ps httprouter.Params) {
    handler.UpdateUserAddress(a.DB, w, r, ps)
}

func (a *App) DisableUser(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, ps httprouter.Params) {
    handler.DisableUser(a.DB, w, r, ps)
}

func (a *App) EnableUser(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, ps httprouter.Params) {
    handler.EnableUser(a.DB, w, r, ps)
}

func (a *App) DeleteUser(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, ps httprouter.Params) {
    handler.DeleteUser(a.DB, w, r, ps)
}

func (a *App) DeleteUserAddress(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, ps httprouter.Params) {
    handler.DeleteUserAddress(a.DB, w, r, ps)
}

// Run the app on it's router
func (a *App) Run(host string) {
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(host, a.Router))
}
```

**config.go:**

```
package config


type Config struct {
    DB *DBConfig
}
 
type DBConfig struct {
    Dialect  string
    Host     string
    Port     int
    User     string
    Password string
    DBname   string
}
 
func GetConfig() *Config {
    return &Config{
        DB: &DBConfig{
            Dialect :  "postgres",
            Host:      "localhost",
            Port:      5433,
            User:      "kriti",
            Password:  "nkx01",
            DBname:    "go_dummy",
        },
    }
}
```

I was learning mockgen and was following this [tutorial](https://dev.to/techschoolguru/mock-db-for-testing-http-api-in-go-and-achieve-100-coverage-4pa9). But that was implemented for sqlc.

I was not able to relate for sqlx. All I understand is we need to create interface for db. Sqlc had emit-interface option so it was doing that interface thing automatically. I am not able to understand where to start from, for mocking db.

Struct related to db:

```
   type DBConfig struct {
        Dialect  string
        Host     string
        Port     int
        User     string
        Password string
        DBname   string
    }
```

**Github code:**

https://github.com/ninjakx/go_app/tree/dev/Downloads/GO_APP-WO_GORM

Comment: Currently I don't have any interfaces in my program. So I ain't able to think what I should do in my code so that I can do testing using mock.

Comment: You can try this package https://github.com/DATA-DOG/go-sqlmock this is just a suggestion

Comment: @ManjeetThakur: I can use that.